# CentOS 6.5 -- > latest 6.7 / 6.x gives Transaction Check Error noarch conflicts with file from package

Tags: centos, installation, upgrade, centos6, centos6.5

I'm trying to update / upgrade CentOS 6.5 version to 6.7 or latest 6.x but getting the following error.

In the snapshot below, I'm showing truncated output and mainly showing the error log while running YUM update or upgrade command. For full log file, please see log .txt file here:  [YUM update or upgrade Transaction Check Error norach conflicts](http://speedy.sh/RAGMH/CentOS-6.5-upgrade-update-error). PS: Under Limited Download, click on "Slow download" and open the log file in some notepad++ type text editor.

What should I do to sucessfully upgrade/update the CentOS version. Thanks.

```
[root@server01 giga]# yum clean all; echo $?
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Cleaning repos: base epel extras google-chrome puppetlabs-deps puppetlabs-products release.update supplemental.release supplemental.release.update updates
Cleaning up Everything
Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors
0
[root@server01 giga]#
[root@server01 giga]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
[root@server01 giga]#
[root@server01 giga]#
[root@server01 giga]#
[root@server01 giga]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/metalink                                                                                                                              |  12 kB     00:00
 * base: ftp.usf.edu
 * epel: mirror.cogentco.com
 * extras: mirrors.advancedhosters.com
 * updates: mirror.team-cymru.org
base                                                                                                                                       | 3.7 kB     00:00
base/primary_db                                                                                                                            | 4.6 MB     00:03
epel                                                                                                                                       | 4.3 kB     00:00
epel/primary_db                                                                                                                            | 5.8 MB     00:00
extras                                                                                                                                     | 3.4 kB     00:00
extras/primary_db                                                                                                                          |  34 kB     00:00
google-chrome                                                                                                                              |  951 B     00:00
google-chrome/primary                                                                                                                      | 1.9 kB     00:00
google-chrome                                                                                                                                                 3/3
puppetlabs-deps                                                                                                                            | 2.5 kB     00:00
puppetlabs-deps/primary_db                                                                                                                 |  27 kB     00:00
puppetlabs-products                                                                                                                        | 2.5 kB     00:00
puppetlabs-products/primary_db                                                                                                             | 166 kB     00:00
release.update                                                                                                                             | 4.0 kB     00:00
release.update/primary_db                                                                                                                  | 4.4 MB     00:00
supplemental.release                                                                                                                       | 2.9 kB     00:00
supplemental.release/primary_db                                                                                                            |  98 kB     00:00
supplemental.release.update                                                                                                                | 2.9 kB     00:00
supplemental.release.update/primary_db                                                                                                     | 2.0 kB     00:00
updates                                                                                                                                    | 3.4 kB     00:00
updates/primary_db                                                                                                                         | 3.9 MB     00:01
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package audit.x86_64 0:2.2-2.el6 will be updated
---> Package audit.x86_64 0:2.3.7-5.el6 will be an update
---> Package audit-libs.x86_64 0:2.2-2.el6 will be updated
---> Package audit-libs.x86_64 0:2.3.7-5.el6 will be an update
---> Package augeas-libs.x86_64 0:1.0.0-5.el6_5.1 will be updated
---> Package augeas-libs.x86_64 0:1.0.0-10.el6 will be an update
---> Package authconfig.x86_64 0:6.1.12-13.el6 will be updated
---> Package authconfig.x86_64 0:6.1.12-23.el6 will be an update
---> Package b43-openfwwf.noarch 0:5.2-4.el6 will be updated
---> Package b43-openfwwf.noarch 0:5.2-10.el6 will be an update
---> Package bash.x86_64 0:4.1.2-15.el6_4 will be updated
---> Package bash.x86_64 0:4.1.2-33.el6_7.1 will be an update
---> Package bfa-firmware.noarch 0:3.2.21.1-2.el6 will be updated
---> Package bfa-firmware.noarch 0:3.2.23.0-2.el6 will be an update
---> Package pciutils.x86_64 0:3.1.10-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package virt-what.x86_64 0:1.11-1.2.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

Installing:
 kernel                                          x86_64                   2.6.32-573.18.1.el6                         updates                                30 M
 kernel-devel                                    x86_64                   2.6.32-573.18.1.el6                         updates                                10 M
Updating:
 audit                                           x86_64                   2.3.7-5.el6                                 base                                  208 k
 audit-libs                                      x86_64                   2.3.7-5.el6                                 base                                   71 k
 augeas-libs                                     x86_64                   1.0.0-10.el6                                base                                  314 k
 authconfig                                      x86_64                   6.1.12-23.el6                               base                                  377 k
 b43-openfwwf                                    noarch                   5.2-10.el6                                  base                                   19 k
 bash                                            x86_64                   4.1.2-33.el6_7.1                            updates                               908 k
 bfa-firmware                                    noarch                   3.2.23.0-2.el6                              base                                  3.2 M
(129/131): yum-3.2.29-69.el6.centos.noarch.rpm                                                                                             | 1.0 MB     00:02
(130/131): yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-30.el6.noarch.rpm                                                                               |  31 kB     00:00
(131/131): yum-utils-1.1.30-30.el6.noarch.rpm                                                                                              | 110 kB     00:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                             1.4 MB/s | 146 MB     01:43
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/bin/extlookup2hiera from install of puppet-3.8.6-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/hiera/backend/puppet_backend.rb from install of puppet-3.8.6-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/hiera/scope.rb from install of puppet-3.8.6-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/hiera_puppet.rb from install of puppet-3.8.6-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/functions/hiera.rb from install of puppet-3.8.6-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/functions/hiera_array.rb from install of puppet-3.8.6-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/functions/hiera_hash.rb from install of puppet-3.8.6-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/functions/hiera_include.rb from install of puppet-3.8.6-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch

Error Summary
-------------

[root@server01 giga]# 

[root@server01 giga]# yum -y upgrade
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.usf.edu
 * epel: mirror.cogentco.com
 * extras: mirrors.advancedhosters.com
 * updates: mirror.team-cymru.org
Setting up Upgrade Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package audit.x86_64 0:2.2-2.el6 will be updated
---> Package audit.x86_64 0:2.3.7-5.el6 will be an update
---> Package audit-libs.x86_64 0:2.2-2.el6 will be updated

 virt-what                                       x86_64                   1.11-1.2.el6                                base                                   24 k

Transaction Summary
==================================================================================================================================================================
Install       5 Package(s)
Upgrade     126 Package(s)

Total size: 146 M
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/bin/extlookup2hiera from install of puppet-3.8.6-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/hiera/backend/puppet_backend.rb from install of puppet-3.8.6-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/hiera/scope.rb from install of puppet-3.8.6-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/hiera_puppet.rb from install of puppet-3.8.6-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/functions/hiera.rb from install of puppet-3.8.6-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/functions/hiera_array.rb from install of puppet-3.8.6-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/functions/hiera_hash.rb from install of puppet-3.8.6-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch
  file /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/functions/hiera_include.rb from install of puppet-3.8.6-1.el6.noarch conflicts with file from package hiera-puppet-1.0.0-1.el6.noarch

Error Summary
-------------

[root@server01 giga]#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for upgrading CentOS 6.5 to 6.6/6.7 was to first: Found this cool site for the hint http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/upgrade-centos-6/ and tried the following.

I tried to first remove puppet and yum update, it still failed with the same error. The issue was with hiera-puppet. With latest puppet (3.x.x which is what you'll get if you update just puppet), **hiera-puppet** comes for free OR you can say it's not required to be installed as a separate step.

## So, solution to upgrade from CentOS 6.5/6.6 to 6.7 (Final) was:

```
# yum -y remove puppet hiera-puppet
# yum -y clean all
# yum -y update glibc* yum* rpm* python*
# yum -y update
# cat /etc/redhat-release; ## This will now give: CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
```